# Server-side checking if cookie stolen

Tags: security, cookies

Is there a way to check if cookie from user A was stolen by user B on the server side?

for example the cookie token/data created using a simple hash function (sha1 for example)

```
hash_of(user_agent,ip+proxy_ip,username,random_session_key)

where user_agent is browser's user agent, 
  ip is the client IP address, 
  proxy_ip is the proxy's IP address the client use, 
  username is the username the user currently login, 
  random_session_key is a random number saved to database when a user logged in
```

if that cookie was stolen and used by another person on the LAN, and the LAN is not using any proxy but a NAT, and the thief was using exactly the same browser (or spoof the user agent), how we on the server side detect that?

Comment: _“and the LAN is not using any proxy but a NAT, and the thief was using exactly the same browser (or spoof the user agent), how we on the server side detect that?”_ – not at all …? To discern two things from one another, you have to have at least _one_ piece of information about each of them that differs. If you can’t find such info, then you can’t tell them apart.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a way. It is called [Secure Cookie Protocol](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~alexliu/publications/Cookie/cookie.pdf).

You are using SSL right? (because if you're not, this entire conversation is pointless).

Well, you encrypt the cookie, but using the SSL session identifier. Assuming that SSL gives you adequate endpoint security (strong ciphers, etc), SCP should protect your data and allow you to tell when another SSL session tries to use the same cookie (because the sessionid changes, and therefore the MAC will change).

```
key = HMAC(user name|expiration time, secret_key)
cookie = user name|expiration time|encrypt(data, key)
cookie = cookie | HMAC( user name|expiration time|data|sessionid, key)
```

So basically, you're creating a unique verification code based on the SSL session identifier.

Note that REMOTE_ADDR or user agent never factors in. The only factors this uses are things that are extremely non-trivial to spoof unless you've physically compromised the client box...

Answer (score 1):

If the cookie has been hijacked,  **it is too late**.  An application must properly defend its secrets.  The useragenet is attacker controlled,  checking this value is insecure by nature.

[OWASP - Insufficient Transport Layer Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection).

[HTTPOnly Cookies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)
["Secure" Cookies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag)

Prevent XSS, CSRF, and Clickjacking, and session fixation.

Comment: Congratz on 1000 answers, Rook!